# Centering around an item using CSS flexbox

Tags: css, centering, flexbox

Using the css flexbox implementation, how would I center three items with each different widths, forcing the middle child to be centered?

Example:
[image]

Comment: any code that you tried so far ?

Comment: Not anything worth mentioning. I tried some different combinations of stuff I found on this website: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Here is a little demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/hqdhem4w/ You will need to define what you want to have centered. The content inside the middle column? That would be easy. - You could also give the container a fixed width and play with margins to "center" it. But I don't think thats what you had in mind.

Comment: Nico O, thanks. That should help clarify even more than my silly paint job. However, note that the entire screen is not used up and that there's space to the left and the right of the flexbox.

Comment: another point of view ... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ktEcB but still not a single idea of your own HTML structure...

Comment: @GCyrillus I could do that, but I'd prefer to do it with a flexbox, which is why I created this post.

Comment: @Locercus ?? display:flex is involved here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ktEcB , what do you mean or want more ?

Comment: @GCyrillus Sorry, I didn't see that you were using flex. Either way, it's still not what I'm looking for. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DInjq

Comment: @Locercus `justify-content:center;` does a great job ;)  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sCvDp min-width/heigght on flex parents gives some warranty if size is given to childs